# Reference of Qunoot Nazila of Umar (RA)

Tags: hadith, reference-request

I want reference of the following Qunoot Nazila of Umar (RA).

[image: This image is from central-mosque.com]

The reference to the image is :

https://central-mosque.com/index.php/Acts-of-Worship/qunut-nazilah-special-collective-supplication-at-the-time-of-extreme-need.html

The following youtube video just says it is narrated in Al-Bayhaqi.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oh67pWYpeyQ

Comment: The references for du'a al-Qunoot as narrated from 'Omar ibn al-Khattab are given in my answer on [Was qunoot part of the qur'an](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/47950/13438). But this strongly differs from that wording.

Answer (score 3):

I found it as part of a longer du'a al-Qunoot in al-Mosannaf 'Abdurazzaq (see [here](https://shamela.ws/book/13174/5332#p1) in Arabic) مصنف عبد الرزاق as a hadith mawquf حديث موقوف (so it was a doing of 'Omar ibn al-Khattab), according the rawy 'Obayd ibn 'Omayr   عُبَيْدَ بْنَ عُمَيْرٍ, 'Omar used to do this qunoot loudly in the second rak'a of sobh (fajr fard prayer!). The completion is what I've already quoted in my answer on [Was Dua-e-Qunut part of the Quran earlier?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39912/was-dua-e-qunut-part-of-the-quran-earlier?noredirect=1&lq=1) (with Basmallah at the beginning of each the so called surat al-Khal'a and al-Hafd)

> بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ ، اللَّهُمَّ إِنَّا ، نَسْتَعِينُكَ ، وَنَسْتَغْفِرُكَ ، وَنُثْنِي عَلَيْكَ وَلا نَكْفُرُكَ ، وَنَخْلَعُ وَنَتْرُكُ مَنْ يَفْجُرُكَ ،
> بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ ، اللَّهُمَّ إِيَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ ، وَلَكَ نُصَلِّي وَنَسْجُدُ ، وَإِلَيْكَ نَسْعَى وَنَحْفِدُ ، نَرْجُو رَحْمَتَكَ ، وَنَخَافُ عَذَابَكَ ، إِنَّ عَذَابَكَ بِالْكُفَّارِ مُلْحَقٌ

Note that al-Bayhaqi has quoted the same in his as-Sunan al-Kubra السنن الكبرى  with the addition of "'Allahuma Ighfir lana  اللهم اغفر لنا" (O Allah forgive us!) at the beginning (see [here](https://shamela.ws/book/7861/3570) in Arabic).

Fatwa islamqa #[271214](https://islamqa.info/ar/271214) -Arabic only- adds it was also compiled by ibn abi Shaybah in his al-Mosannaf and al-Bayhaqi has qualified it as sahih.