# What is Qunût an-Nawâzil?

Tags: dua, islamic-basis

What is Qunût an-Nawâzil? I came across this term while reading a book, I have never heard this term before and unfortunately the book barely explained what it was. From what I was able to guess it is some sort of special supplication ritual.

What is Qunût an-Nawâzil? How is it performed? What is the history behind it?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam stackexchange . Take our [tour] and check our [help] for more information on our site and model. Here a relevant post: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49617/reference-of-qunoot-nazila-of-umar-ra