# Understanding of Dua Qunoot regarding non-muslim friendship

Tags: quran, hadith, tafseer, hadith-interpretation, non-muslim

The translation of Dua Qunoot is as follows:
"O Allah! We implore You for help and beg forgiveness of You and believe in You and rely on You and extol You and we are thankful to You and are not ungrateful to You and **we alienate and forsake those who disobey You**. O, Allah! You alone do we worship and for You do we pray and prostrate and we betake to please You and present ourselves for the service in Your cause and we hope for Your mercy and fear Your chastisement. Undoubtedly, Your torment is going to overtake infidels O Allah!"

Above it says: "...we alienate and forsake those who disobey You..." does it say to not be friends with non-muslims?

If yes, how do we reconcile with other quranic verses that say in the context of non-muslims:

- "God does not forbid you from those who do not fight you because of religion and do not expel you from your homes - from being righteous toward them and acting justly toward them. Indeed, God loves those who act justly” (Quran 60: 8)"
- And do not argue with the People of the Scripture except in a way that is best, except for those who commit injustice among them, and say, "We believe in that which has been revealed to us and revealed to you. And our God and your God is one; and we are Muslims [in submission] to Him."

...and various other verses and hadith that talk about showing tolerance to other religions.

Comment: "Alienate and forsake" does not mean be unjust with them. It is still good to act just and kindly to non-Muslims.

Answer (score 2):

According to this fatwa on islamweb #[48460](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/48460/%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%AD-%D8%AF%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D9%86%D9%88%D8%AA) (in Arabic).

Your interpretation of the significant parts is simply wrong:

> O Allah! We implore You for help and beg forgiveness of You and believe in You and rely on You and extol You and we are thankful to You and are not ungrateful to You and **we alienate and forsake those who disobey You**.
>   اللهم إنا نستعينك ونستهديك , ونستغفرك ونتوب إليك , ونؤمن بك ونتوكل عليك , ونثني عليك الخير
>   كله , نشكرك لا نكفرتك , **ونخلع نترك من يفجرك**

Here the bold part is related to the literal meaning of kufr كفر which is rejection and opposition (not disbelieve: which is an expression of these in religious matters).
In Mirqat al-Mafatih sharh Mishkat al-Masabih [مرقاة المفاتيح شرح مشكاة المصابيح](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=2548&idfrom=0&idto=0&flag=1&bk_no=79&ayano=0&surano=0&bookhad=0) of Mulla 'Alu al-Qari, you may read in the long commentary to the du'a al-Qunoot which was attributed to 'Ali () in the Sunan books of [ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1312340), [abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/8/12) and [an-Nasa-i](https://sunnah.com/nasai/20/150), when quoting the du'a attributed to 'Umar ():

> والكفر : نقيض الشكر
>   Kufr (rejection) is the opposite of thankfulness.

Also note that the earlier sentence actually says:

> we are thankful to You and are not ungrateful to You
>   نشكرك لا نكفرتك

Which means we are thankful unlike those who commit kufr (rejection) by being ungrateful to You and so the bold sentence actually means:

> We use all of Your gifts to worship you and being grateful, and we don't use them to be ungrateful as this means rejecting Your gifts (and kindness).

Furthermore be aware that this special du'a al-Qunoot is also known as du'a Qunoot an-Nazilah this means it is a form which was performed when something (usually bad) happens. (See also [Reference of Qunoot Nazila of Umar (RA)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49617/reference-of-qunoot-nazila-of-umar-ra))

Basically the Muslims attitude towards non-Muslims is known and well defined in the qur'an:

- to  fight enemies and people who hate Islam (in first place those who ally against Muslims),
- to be more friendly to those who befriend Muslims (especially those who live under Muslim ruling)
- and being cautious with all other kinds no matter if they are living in Muslim countries or elsewhere.